# Css Left property issue

Tags: html, css

Using the left property in `#image-list>.image-container>p` seems to center the `<p>` element in the div with id `#image-list` and not its parent. I do not understand what I did wrong.

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  list = document.getElementById("image-list");
  item = list.children[0];
  item = item.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("image-list").appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
#image-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4vmin;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

#image-list>.image-container>.image {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 56vmin;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% center;
}

#image-list>.image-container>p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 2rem;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px black;
}

#image-list>.image-container {
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-list">
  <div class="image-container">
    <p>hello world</p>
    <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" draggable="false">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn">add image</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the `<p>` element within its parent, which is .`image-container`, you can add `position: relative` to `.image-container` and set `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` on `#image-list > .image-container > p`.

try this example :

```
#image-list>.image-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#image-list>.image-container>p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 2rem;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning is with respect to the edges of the closest positioned ancestor.

"positioned" means "has a `position` property that is not `static`.

You haven't set the `position` property of `.image-container`, so it has the default value, which is `static`.

---

`#image-list` has `position: absolute` so it is the closest positioned ancestor so your positioning is done with respect to that element's edges.